# ShapeableImageView to Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, view, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a ViewGroup with a ShapeableImageView. I need to render it on the google map, for that I convert it to Bitmap. But in doing so, the ShapeableImageView overlaps parent's background. In the xml (via include) everything works fine

I made a copy of the ShapeableImageView and tried to change the ShapeableImageView, according to my observations, a white background is drawn at the corners and then through PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT it is cut out due to which transparent space appears. Maybe I'm wrong

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutPin"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_pin"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPin"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_preview"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedImageView"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_map_pin_subtitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.H5_12_16_BO"
        android:textColor="@color/map_pin_subtitle_color"
        tools:text="1 200 Р"
        />

</LinearLayout>


fun View.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
    if (measuredHeight <= 0) {
        measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(measuredWidth, measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    layout(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight)
    draw(canvas)

    return bitmap
}


binding.root.toBitmap()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to use workaround, put pin backgdround over imageview, with center cut